# My app is in production status but when i click on 'View on Google Play' it show error

Tags: google-play, google-play-services

[image]

[image]

My app is in production status but when I click on 'View on Google Play' it shows, "We're sorry, the requested URL was not found on this server.

Comment: Are you releasing your app for the first time or is this an update?

Comment: Yes ,i am releasing app for the first time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It says "We're sorry, the requested URL was not found on this server" because as it shows on the screenshot, the app is still in review. Once your app will have been reviewed, then you will be able to find your app on the Google Play Store. From my experience, an app review can take from 1-7 days but may sometimes take longer.

Comment: Thanks,it took a few days but now my app is live on playstore